# Copy subfolders containing at least n files

Tags: bash, find, file-copy

I have a folder `root_folder` containing a lot of subfolders. Each of these subfolders contains a small number of files (between 1 and 20) and I want to copy all the subfolders containing at least 5 files into another folder `new_folder`. I have found how to print the folders that interest me: https://superuser.com/questions/617050/find-directories-containing-a-certain-number-of-files but not how to copy them.

Comment: is new folder outside the folder that you're working on?

Comment: yes, its relative path is like `..\new_folder` when I am inside `root_folder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a for loop on the find result and copy the folder with -R :

```
IFS=$'\n'
for source_folder in "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{}\t'; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; |  
awk -F"\t" '$NF>=5{print $1}');" do 
  if [[ "$source_folder" != "." ]]; then 
    cp -R "$source_folder" /destination/folder
  fi
done
```

Comment: it seems to copy all subfolders...

Comment: Yeah depends from where do you execute the script. Execute it from inside root_folder, or replace `find .` with `find /path/to/root_folder/`, does it work that way ?

Comment: I executed it from inside `root_folder` but the `find` command seems to return also `.` in its list and I suppose that is why all subfolders are copied. I am looking for a way to remove it from the list

Comment: Hmmm yes you are right, the first hit is the `.` folder, I didn't check it thouroughly.  I added an if statement to my solution to avoid processing the `.` folder.

Comment: @mazs : Instead of the `if` statement you may consider adding `-mindepth 1` for `find`.

Comment: This is gratuitously complex and gratuitously breaks on file names containing spaces. Don't parse the output of `find`, use `for source_folder in */`, and so on.

Comment: In the meantime i found the solution to loop the `find` results without breaking it on file names which contain spaces.  Add IFS=$'\n' at the beginning of the script (if you don't use a sscript, you might want to consider saving IFS and restoring it), and quote the `find` command substitution. Corrected post to reflect these.

Answer (score 3):

Below script works for your case :

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while read -rd '' line
do  files=("$line"/* "$line"/.*)
count=${#files[@]};((count-=2))
if [ $count -ge 5 ]
then
cp -R "$line" ../newfolder/
fi
done
```

**Note :** This should be executed from the base folder as I am using relative paths.

Comment: This is gratuitously complex and gratuitously breaks on file names containing spaces. Don't parse the output of `find`, use `var=(*/)` and likewise for the file count.

Comment: @Gilles : I have changed the script to address the issues you have pointed out :D

Comment: Now this breaks on file names containing newlines.  :)  Don't parse the output of other commands to do file ops (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). @Gilles already suggested a robust way using an glob and an array. `count=(*/); (( ${#count[@]} > 5 )) && ...`

Comment: @unop . Edited. This one works for  folders with newlines and folders that start with a `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the subdirectories of a directory:

```
for subdir in root_folder/*/; do
  if [ -L "${subdir%/}" ]; then continue; fi
  …
done
```

The `if [ -L …` line skips symbolic links to directories. Omit it if you want to include symbolic links to directories or if you know there won't be any.

Directories whose name begins with a `.` (dot directories) won't be included. To include them, in bash, run `shopt -s dotglob`.

To count the number of files in a directory, in bash, store them in an array and count the number of elements. Run `shopt -s nullglob` to get 0 for an empty directory (otherwise the glob pattern `*` remains unexpanded if it matches nothing, so you get 1 instead of 0).

Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
for subdir in root_folder/*/; do
  if [ -L "${subdir%/}" ]; then continue; fi
  files=("$subdir"/*)
  if ((${#files[@]} >= 5)); then
    cp -Rp "$subdir" new_folder/
  fi
done
```